# how to convert the query to hibernate query language?

Tags: mysql, hql

how to write this query in hibernate query language

```
select * from preferred_space p, building b, floor f, space_type st, space s
    where p.user_id=11
    and p.space_id=s.id
    and s.building_id=b.id
    and s.floor_id=f.id
    and s.space_type_id=st.id 
    order by p.id;
```

If I do it this way it is showing me an error?

```
 String sql =    "from     PreferredSpace p, Space s, Building b, Floor f, SpaceType st " +
                 "where    p.userId = ? " +
                 "and      p.spaceId = s.id" +
                 "and      s.buildingId = b.id" +
                 "and      s.floorId = f.id" +
                 "and      s.spaceTypeId = st.id" +
                 "order by p.id";
```

error:

```
ERROR o.h.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter - line 1:242: unexpected token: s
16:18:17.569 [http-bio-8080-exec-24] ERROR o.h.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter - line 1:242: unexpected token: s
antlr.NoViableAltException: unexpected token: s
```

shows the same error for every row that starts with "s." and also for "by".

Comment: And the error it shows you is? Perhaps something about `idand` not being a column in `Space`? The fact that you didn't post the error here says to me you didn't read it. One of the best things you can do for yourself is to start reading messages that come up on the screen. Sometimes they don't make sense, but they'll help, I promise.

Comment: ERROR o.h.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter - line 1:242: unexpected token: s
16:18:17.569 [http-bio-8080-exec-24] ERROR o.h.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter - line 1:242: unexpected token: s
antlr.NoViableAltException: unexpected token: s

Comment: it shows the above error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add spaces:

```
String sql = "from     PreferredSpace p, Space s, Building b, Floor f, SpaceType st " +
             "where    p.userId = ? " +
             "and      p.spaceId = s.id " +
             "and      s.buildingId = b.id " +
             "and      s.floorId = f.id " +
             "and      s.spaceTypeId = st.id " +
             "order by p.id";
```

Comment: Thanks you! forgot to check to spaces!